# How to load/import dll with MEF out of metro app?

Tags: c#, mef, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I've trying to write a extendable metro app using MEF. I got it working with a local extension (inside of the current assembly). Now I want to load a external dll. The `DirectoryCatalog` seems to be not present in .net 4.5. So I tried to use `ApplicationCatalog` but I got the following error while calling `SatisfyImportsOnce`: `Assembly.LoadFrom is not supported in AppX.`.

Here's me code:

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
ApplicationCatalog catApp = new ApplicationCatalog();
AggregateCatalog cat = new AggregateCatalog(catalog, catApp);
_compositionService = cat.CreateCompositionService();
_compositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

Any suggestions what's going wrong?

I've placed the dll in the Appx directory and run VS11 Beta as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to some supporter in the MEF forums and he confirms that ApplicationCatalog could not be used out of a metro app. So this question is not solveable but could be closed.
[Source Thread](http://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/348566)

Answer (score 1):

Your external library reaches outside the allowed sandbox of Metro. The .NET framework in in the Metro environment is limited, similar to the WP7 or Micro Framework. There are a lot of things cut. If your external DLL isn't built using those constrained libraries, then the compiler will disallow its use.

Comment: I created the project for the dll as Windows Metro style Class Library.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed that. Did you set the output to a WinMD file? http://sempf.net/post/Referencing-a-C-class-library-in-HTML5-Metro-UI.aspx

Comment: No, I didn't because WinMD files are only allowed to implement WinRT interfaces. But my Class implements the IExtension interface of the core project (see last sentence in your linked articel). I think I need this Interface for Import/Export, or is there a other way I've missed?

Comment: It does, but this goes back to my original answer - you can't step outside the sandbox of MetroUI. They enforce that with the WinMD format. To use the library in MetroUI, it has to be WinMD. To be WinMD, you have to only implement allowed interfaces. That's the catch22 with MetroUI apps. You can't use a whole lot of outside code, even if it is benign.

Comment: Currently it seems, that the ApplicationCatalog is not supported even though it is available. I removed all includes and dlls/WinMDs and the error still pops up.

Comment: There was a problem with some caching of files that I ran into in another answer earlier this week - maybe try to do a Clean and Build or manually delete the temp files.